# How to troubleshoot missing hardware functionality in Win 10 PE WDS boot environment

Tags: windows, drivers, wds

I am working to inject drivers into our Windows 10 PE WDS boot environment. First hurdle was getting the correct NIC driver installed, but now that is done I am hitting a wall in getting the touchpad working. Adding the entire CAB worth of drivers to the boot image didn't work, surprisingly. What are next steps to figure out what problem device(s) may be the issue, that I would otherwise be able to see in Device Manager, but only have access to the Command Prompt. Any other tips to figure out what driver is missing?

Comment: What computer do you have? It may be easier to identify the OEM and manually integrate the necessary drivers depending on the Mobo arch

Comment: @ElliotLabsLLC - Thanks. Am perusing that now.